# GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h file is not found

Tags: xcode, react-native-ios, info.plist

I have a issue, regarding Xcode, in react-native permission file
 in which GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h file is not found.

How to fix this?

Already changed Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File to

```
${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h
```

but it did not solve.

issue is:

> :1:10: fatal error:
>   '/Users/DAMAGE/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EmployWise-fzbhiywasjfdjnfqjsfnxjbhahzs/Build/Products/GeneratedInfoPlistDotEnv.h'
>   file not found

Answer (score 3):

Was getting this from react-native-config cocoapod. But its been fixed in v1.4.11. Was due to the older version not writing output script variables, which XCode 14 requires

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes when react native is not able to link to the configuration file like .env file created in your react native environment. If you have used any react native config framework like react-native-config. then make sure this framework is linked for your iOS environment as shown below

```
    react-native link react-native-config
```

If you are using react-native version >= 0.60 then follow the below steps after linking is done.
 Go to ios folder and run pod install.

Next do the following:
1. Remove Derived Data from Xcode
2. Clean Build Folder
3. Build the project again

Comment: If auto linking is not working , link it manually. In Xcode project , 1.Go to Libraries folder. Right click and select Add files -> Browse to "node modules/react-native-config/ios folder. Select `ReactNativeConfig.xcodeproj`. Click Add. This will add the config project to your existing project. 2. Now select Project. Go to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> Add `libReactNativeConfig.a`. Now build and run your project.

Comment: In my case the error happened after adding an extension service. All I need to do is to follow the 2nd step suggested by @Shweta (i.e. Add libReactNativeConfig.a to the libraries of the extension service).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to add a new target for [rn-extensions-share](https://github.com/RocketChat/rn-extensions-share) and forgot to add all necessary libraries for that new target.

[image: Correct libs to link with in shar extension target]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my solution was to change the Xcode build system from "Legacy Build System" to "New Build System" in the Workspace Settings under the File menu